# How to handle STDOUT logs in K8s?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging, fluent-bit

In a Docker environment my Java-App logs on STDOUT via log4j, the messages will be sent to a Graylog instance. There is no special logging config besides configuring the Console-Appender to use JsonLayout.

My docker-compose.yml snippet:

```
logging:
  driver: gelf
  options:
    gelf-address: "tcp://[GRAYLOG_HOST]:[PORT]"
    tag: "[...]"
```

Everything works fine there. But we are thinking about changing this environment to K8s.

There will be a Graylog instance in K8s, too. It looks like that there is no K8s equivalent for the docker-compose.yml logging settings. It seems that I have to use some kind of logging agent, e.g. fluent-bit. But the documentation of fluent-bit looks like that it only can collect logs from a log file as input (and some more), but not from STDOUT.

I have the following questions:

- Is there another possibility to read the logs directly from STDOUT and send them into Graylog?
- If I have to log the log messages into a log file to be read from fluent-bit: Do I have to configure log4j to do some roll-over strategies to prevent, that the log file will be bigger and bigger? I do not want to "waste" my resources "just" for logging.
- How do you handle application logs in K8s?

Maybe I misunderstand the logging principles in K8s. Feel free to explain it to me.

Comment: There is a [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) section in the Kubernetes documentation; but IME it is almost always configured with a cluster-wide DaemonSet to collect logs, not configured on a per-pod basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there another possibility to read the logs directly from STDOUT and send them into Graylog?

Fluent Bit allows for data [collection through STDIN](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/standard-input). Redirect your application STDOUT to Fluent Bit's STDIN and you are set.

> If I have to log the log messages into a log file to be read from fluent-bit: Do I have to configure log4j to do some roll-over strategies to prevent, that the log file will be bigger and bigger? I do not want to "waste" my resources "just" for logging.

In this case you can use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

> How do you handle application logs in K8s?

Three possible ways:

1. Application directly output their traces in external systems (eg. databases).
2. Sidecar container with embedded logging agent that collect application traces and send them to a store (again database for example).
3. Cluster-wide centralized logging (eg. ELK stack)

---

I'd recommend you to use [sidecar container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-logging-agent) for log collection. This is probably most widely used solution.

Comment: Hi p10l. Thank you for your reply. This will help me a lot